# Angular app breaks when I introduce ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Fairly new to angular, so would very much appreciate some help. I got a simple framework up an running but as soon as I introduce the ui-grid it breaks and I don't see any errors in the console but the screen is blank. I got it replicated in plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Qi2FgTYt3RncXWKyptdU?p=preview

Everything work fine until I un-comment this line in index.html:

`<script src="basicGridCtrl.js"></script>`

Comment: Line 1 in basicGridCtrl.js should be var app = angular.module('blueBerryAdmin');

Comment: Hello, if the [answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34462133/306921) by [Masanov Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4227058/manasov-daniel) answered your question (which seems so) then you should mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in AngularJS all dependencies are injected in app.js

`angular.module('blueBerryAdmin',['ngTouch', 'ui.grid',"ngRoute", "ngResource"]);`

Does this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTz5uW5kTKjgoQrKlylE?p=preview) work for you?

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated. I made your change on plunker and it works. I've just started using it and it looked like a decent way to communicate code and issues. Anyway thanks again.